# Prevent multiple span in a line from overlapping (Clojure hiccup code but purely css related)

Tags: css, clojure, hiccup

How can I group two `div`s inside a `span` (one below other and the `div` contains text and has a fixed width) and display multiple `span` like this in fixed width `td` tag. I am able to do so, but my `span` are overlapping. If the space in a line is full then the next `span` should come in next line.

Comment: You should not place block elements (like a `div`) inside inline elements (like a `span`)

Comment: Where is a live URL, or link to jsfiddel/webdevout? We cannot help you, if there is no way to play with your css/html.

Comment: Okay i converted the span to div, but still using 'display:inline-block' is not preventing them from overlapping...the parent div are still overlapping.

Answer (score 4):

You need to correct your markup.

You are not allowed to place block-level Elements (like `div`) into inline elements (like `span`). Doing so will make your markup invalid and mess with the layout, since inline elements have restriction regarding `width` and `margin`.

Either declare `display:block` or `display:inline-block` on your spans, or even better convert them to divs. This should most likely fix your issue.

Comment: Okay i converted the span to div, but still using 'display:inline-block' is not preventing them from overlapping...the parent div are still overlapping.

Comment: @Avi go to jsfiddle.net and provide a link to your sample markup.